# Starting of windows service in child process with elevation of privileges with UAC OFF

Tags: c#, manifest, uac, privileges, elevation

There is a C# program. It's started under non-admin user in Windows 7. UAC is ON.
This program runs child process:

```
  webClientProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
  webClientProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @".\StartWebClient.exe";
  webClientProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
  webClientProcess.Start();
```

app.manifest of child process has following setting:

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

StartWebClient.exe just starts WebClient windows service and return.

If UAC is ON we have pop-up prompt for admin password and everything is OK.

If UAC is OFF (user is not admin!) we have no prompt, of course, and then when we start WebClient service:

```
var sc = new ServiceController("WebClient");
if (sc.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
{    
    sc.Start();
}
```

we have an error: **Cannot open WebClient service on computer '.'.**

It's due to there was no admin password pop up window.

Question: Is there any way to start service in this case?

I couldn't find solution here or in MSDN. If this situation is "wrong use case" in Microsoft opinion, may be somebody know a link to appropriate MSDN article? I have no goal to start service with some hacks, if it is forbidden - OK, but I couldn't find confirmation in MSDN.

Comment: Starting a service requires admin privileges by default, so if the user can't elevate then it ain't ever going to start.  A basic workaround is to have it started at machine startup.  Giving the user to right to tinker with the service [is possible](http://woshub.com/set-permissions-on-windows-service/#h2_2).  Fairly hacky, serverfault.com may have a better approach.